# Insertion Sort not sorting first element?

Tags: c++, algorithm, insertion-sort

My implementation of insertion sort seems to be working with the exception of sorting the very first element. I have a small test case here. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my algorithm?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;



void Insert(int *S, int k)
{
        int key = S[k];
        int j = k-1;
        while(j>0 && S[j] > key)
        {
                S[j+1] = S[j];
                j--;
        }

        S[j+1] = key;
}


void Insertionsort(int S[], int n)
{
        if(n>1)
                Insertionsort(S,n-1);
        Insert(S,n);

}

int main()
{
        srand ( time(NULL) );
        int S1_8[8];
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
                S1_8[i] = rand()%100;

        Insertionsort(S1_8,8);

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
                cout << S1_8[i] << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't explain the problem, but there is definitely an issue in the last iteration, when `Insert(S,8)` is called. According to the definition of the `Insert` function that will access `S[8]`, which is a non-existing element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time `Insert` is called, it is passed  `int key = S[8];`

`S[8]` is not **within array bounds**.

Make that

```
void Insertionsort(int S[], int n)
{
        if(n>1)
                Insertionsort(S,n-1);
        Insert(S,n-1);

}
```

Also, in your while condition,  it must be

```
while(j>=0 && S[j] > key)
```

**[Link to Code](http://ideone.com/KXHs9)**

Comment: +1, but you also changed the condition in the while loop to `j>=0` instead of `j>0`. That is correct but should be mentioned and explained in the answer.

Comment: Thank you both. If I want to count the number of component wise comparisons made by `Insert`, do I increment a counter inside the while loop or outside the while loop?

Comment: That only count when S[j] > key is true. Don't I still need to increment when S[j] > key is not true - thus having a counter incremented inside AND outside?

Comment: Only one more comparison is done, which isn't caught inside the while. That is when while encounters `S[j] <= key`. After that comparison, the key is assigned and the routine ends. So you can just add that 1 to it.